# google-api-nodejs-client is not fetching details

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using google-api-nodejs-client oauth2.js and console is not showing any errors but no profile details are getting fetched of the signed in user in console. Here, is my code where "Hey there.2" is the last line that is getting displayed in console. Can someone point me the incorrect part?
I have included oauth2.keys.json in the directory.

Edit: I just found that Hey there.3 got displayed but after a very big time interval.

```
 'use strict';


const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const opn = require('opn');
const destroyer = require('server-destroy');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const plus = google.plus('v1');
console.log("Hey there.1");

 /**
  * To use OAuth2 authentication, we need access to a a CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, AND REDIRECT_URI.  To get these credentials for your application, visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials.
  */
 const keyPath = path.join(__dirname, 'oauth2.keys.json');
 let keys = {redirect_uris: ['']};
 if (fs.existsSync(keyPath)) {
   keys = require(keyPath).web;
 }

 /**
  * Create a new OAuth2 client with the configured keys.
  */
 const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
   keys.client_id,
   keys.client_secret,
   keys.redirect_uris[0]
 );

 /**
  * This is one of the many ways you can configure googleapis to use authentication credentials.
  In this method, we're setting a global reference for all APIs.
  Any other API you use here, like google.drive('v3'), will now use this auth client.
  You can also override the auth client at the service and method call levels.
  */
 google.options({auth: oauth2Client});

 /**
  * Open an http server to accept the oauth callback.
  The only request to our webserver is to /callback?code=<code>
  */
 async function authenticate(scopes) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // grab the url that will be used for authorization                
     const authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
       access_type: 'offline',
       scope: scopes.join(' '),
     });
     console.log("Hey there.2");                                    
     const server = http
     .createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            console.log("Hey there.3");
          if (req.url.indexOf('google') > -1) {
            //const qs = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);
            const qs = new url.URL(req.url).searchParams;
            res.end('Authentication successful! Please return to the console.');
            server.destroy();
            //const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.code);
            const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
            oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;
            resolve(oauth2Client);
            console.log("Hey there.4");
          }
         } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(e);
         }
       })
       .listen(3000, () => {
         // open the browser to the authorize url to start the workflow
         opn(authorizeUrl, {wait: false}).then(cp => cp.unref())
         ;
       });
     destroyer(server);
   });
 }

 async function runSample() {
   // retrieve user profile
   const res = await plus.people.get({userId: 'me'});
   console.log(res.data);
   console.log("Hey there.5");
   console.log(userId);
 }

 const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'];
    authenticate(scopes)
   .then(client => runSample(client))
   .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: What is the Google server returning for tokens at this line: `oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;` ?

Comment: @JohnHanley the application has to request an access token from the Google Authorization Server and then after taking the token from the response, it sends the token. But here, I don't know whether  these things are happening or not because my flow is not reaching up to that line so i can't even check.

Comment: Based upon your updated comment (Hey there 3) I would guess that the call back URL in the Google Console for your Client ID does not match how you have your listener configured. The URL and PORT must match. Add more details to your question with the URLs that you are using for the console and in your code. Your callback url (redirect) should be http://localhost:3000.

Comment: @JohnHanley My redirect URI as well as callback URL is http://localhost:3000. The page is getting stuck after I am giving the application access to the google account(clicking on the allow button) saying "localhost didn’t send any data".

Comment: That means that your callback is not working. The browser will redirect to your listener URL. Either the path is wrong, the port is wrong, something is blocking this action, your listener is not actually listening.

Comment: Use Chrome. Press F-12 to open the debugger. Go to Network. Now go to your page and authenticate. You can see each step. After you click OK to authorize, look for the line that calls your callback code.

Comment: @JohnHanley can you tell me how can i find what is wrong because port is 3000 in the code as well as the credentials file. And how can i change the redirect url (if i have already changed it in the credentials file).

Comment: What is the Chrome debugger showing you. Note: The callback url in the credentials file is a comment, you must set the URL in the Google Console for your Client ID.

Comment: @JohnHanley debugger is showing "Stalled" and i have changed redirect URL in the Google console only. But Hey there.3 is getting consoled only when redirect URL is http://localhost:3000.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say in your last comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley as you said in your previous comment, i have changed the redirect URL in the Google console to get my credentials but still "Hey there.3" is only getting printed when i am changing it again to http://localhost:3000. Can you point me the error.